# slim framework htaccess 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fedora

I know there are many such questions and I have tried them all but none seems to work.

User directories are configured and so I can open `localhost/~h22` (h22 is username)

http://localhost/~h22/slim/index.php/hello/Megh works but http://localhost/~h22/slim/hello/Megh doesnot work giving 404 not found error

Exact error in browser

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home/h22/public_html/slim/index.php was not found on this server.
```

`.htaccess` file is parsed as writing gibberish in the file gives internal server error.

My code is located in

```
/home/h22/public_html/slim
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
└── vendor
    ...
```

*index.php*:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, " . $name;
});
$app->run();
?>
```

*.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

*/etc/httpd/conf.d/slim.conf*:

```
<Directory "/home/h22/public_html/slim">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I resolved this.

Here you need to add line

```
RewriteBase /~h22/slim/
```

after `RewriteEngine On`

So in any other project if your URL is `localhost/abcd`,
you need to write `RewriteBase /abcd`